# How to save page elements on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

To begin with this is how page looks like: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Oty.jpg)

### The idea:

-I was thinking to get elements information and put it in array with `$.each` as soon, they are added dynamically to the page . After that I would store it into Session Storage, and check if it is empty on every loading of the page, and if it is not I would append it to the page.

### The Problem:

I cannot get array(assoc) to work. I need something like that:

```
array['meals'] = {meal_number:{'food_name':food_name,'food_state':food_state.. and so on}};
```

With words, I need an array in this case :`['meals']` in which depend on element data  i store number of meal as  `{meal_number:}` and each meal number is populated with information, for the meal(which I am taking from elements), in this case food_name,food_state ...

### The Code:

```
$('.cd-food-meal-container').find('.cd-added-food').map(function() {
 var food_name = $(this).find('#cd-food-name').text();
 var food_state = $(this).find('.cd-food-state').text();
 var food_image = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
 var food_carbs = $(this).find('.cd-carbs').text();
 var food_prots = $(this).find('.cd-prots').text();
 var food_fats = $(this).find('.cd-fats').text();
 var food_kkals = $(this).find('.cd-kkals').text();
 var number_of_meal_from_element = $(this).closest('.cd-food-meal-container').data('meal_number');
 var array_meal_number = 'meal_' + number_of_meal_from_element;
 var meal_id = $(this).data('meal_food_id');

 meal_array['meals'] = meal_array.push({[array_meal_number]:{
  "meal_number": array_meal_number,
  "food_name": food_name,
  "food_state": food_state,
  "food_image": food_image,
  "food_carbs": food_carbs,
  "food_prots": food_prots,
  "food_fats": food_fats,
  'food_kkals': food_kkals,
  'id': meal_id
 }});

});
```

// I am adding elements with switch. I am just pasting it in case you need additional info, how am i appending elements to page.

```
switch (meal_number) {
             case 1:
              if ($('.cd-food-meal-container[data-meal_number="1"]').data('meal_number') == meal_number) {


               $('.cd-food-meal-container[data-meal_number="1"]').append(food_result);


              } else {
               $('.cd-foods').append(foods_container);
               $('.cd-food-meal-container[data-meal_number="1"]').append(food_result);
              }

              //Добавяме калкулацията на макронутриенти за всяко меню
              $('.cd-food-meal-container[data-meal_number="1"]').find('.cd-carbs').each(function() {
               sum_carbs += parseFloat($(this).text());
              });


              $('.cd-food-meal-container[data-meal_number="1"]').find('.cd-prots').each(function() {
               sum_prots += parseFloat($(this).text());
              });


              $('.cd-food-meal-container[data-meal_number="1"]').find('.cd-fats').each(function() {
               sum_fats += parseFloat($(this).text());
              });
              $('.cd-food-meal-container[data-meal_number="1"]').find('.cd-kkals').each(function() {
               sum_kkals += parseFloat($(this).text());
              });



              $('.cd-food-meal-container[data-meal_number="1"]').children('.total_meal_values').remove();
              $('.cd-food-meal-container[data-meal_number="1"]').append("<div class = 'total_meal_values'><div><b>Макронутриенти</b></div><table class = 'cd-sm-table'><tr><th>Въглехидрат</th><th>Протеин</th><th>Мазнини</th><th>Калории</th></tr><hr><tr><td class = 'cd-sm-carb-total'>" + sum_carbs + "</td><td class= 'cd-sm-prot-total'>" + sum_prots + "</td><td class= 'cd-sm-fats-total'>" + sum_fats + "</td><td class = 'cd-sm-cals-total'>" + sum_kkals + "</td></tr></table></div>");



              break;
```

### Questions:

- How to populate array the way i want it?
- How to call the `food_name` for given sub-array?
- Is this the right way, to store elements, and append them, to save them from dissapearing on page refresh ?

Comment: I think you don't want an array, but an object. Use an array if you want to use numbered index. If you want to use names as key/index, use an object. Therefore, don't use `push`. About the right way to store: it feels quite strange to store it on the client side, don't you want to implement a session with a "shopping cart" on the server side? If you really want to save it on the client side, why not using the local/session storage!

Comment: Well If i store it as an Object, the console returns only the last record, and its not doing the job.And yes i will store it with session storage as i have written up in The Idea.There is what is the result if i use Object http://prntscr.com/k4mv21. I need result for each element, not only one per meal ;(

Answer (score 1):

This way is definitely incorrect (for more than one reason)

```
meal_array['meals'] = meal_array.push{[array_meal_number]:{
  "meal_number": array_meal_number,
  "food_name": food_name,
  "food_state": food_state,
  // ...
}};
```

- `meal_array['meals']` looks like an object `{meals: ...}` (not an array).
- `array = array.push()` this is not how you add to array. Mere `array.push()` would be ok.
- You don't have opening parentheses after `push` in `meal_array.push{[array_meal_number]`. It should be `meal_array.push(`.

PS: To add to an object, you probably want to do:

```
 Object.assign(meal_array['meals'], {
   [array_meal_number]:{
     "meal_number": array_meal_number,
     "food_name": food_name,
     "food_state": food_state,
     "food_image": food_image,
     "food_carbs": food_carbs,
     // ...
   }
 });
```

Comment: Sorry for the push, i was editing the snippet and forgot to add the brackets.I tried with object and the problem there was it is returning only 1 result instead of all meals on page. I tried your method, and it gives me error Object.assing is not a function.

Comment: It's `Object.assign`, not `Object.assing`

Comment: Well fixed it, and variables, still trying this and it is working, but returns same information of elements multiplied by elements... http://prntscr.com/k4oq6t